# C# with object types the method Object.Equals (object a, object b) returns the wrong result

Tags: c#, object, reflection, compare, system.reflection

I need to check the object (not all properties), with primitive types everything works correctly, but with object types the method `Object.Equals(object a, object b)` returns the wrong result.

```
        public static bool IsModified<T>(T newProp, T oldProp) where T : class
    {
        List<string> IgnoreProps = new List<string> { "UpdatedOn", "UpdatedById", "UpdatedBy", "RowVersion" };

        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach(PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (IgnoreProps.Contains(prop.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var propType = prop.PropertyType;

            var newValue = prop.GetValue(newProp);
            var oldValue = prop.GetValue(oldProp);

            newValue = Convert.ChangeType(newValue, propType);
            oldValue = Convert.ChangeType(oldValue, propType);

            var a = Equals(newValue, oldValue); // return incorrect value

            if (!Equals(newValue, oldValue))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

First object

[image]

Second object

[image]

Comment: Don't add relevant information as images to the question, please add the values as text. Also does your type override the `Equals` method?

Answer (score 0):

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for
> reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference
> equality means the object references that are compared refer to the
> same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have
> the same binary representation.
> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)

As you have two different references (`var newValue`, `var oldValue`) you get `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a class `MyCustomClass` and the following example:

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public string txt;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyCustomClass cl1 = new MyCustomClass()
    {
        txt = "a"
    };
    MyCustomClass cl2 = new MyCustomClass()
    {
        txt = "a"
    };

    if (Equals(cl1, cl2))
        Console.WriteLine("equal");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("NOT equal");
}
```

If you run the above code you will get as output `NOT equal`. This is because .net will try to compare only the references between the 2 instances of the class. eg, if you write:

```
    if (Equals(cl1, cl1))
        Console.WriteLine("equal");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("NOT equal");
```

this will result to `equal` as you compare the same instance `cl1` to `cl1`.

For you in order to do comparisons with the Equals method you will have to overwrite it in your class. For example your class should become:

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public string txt;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //Check for null and compare run-time types.
        if ((obj == null) || !this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            MyCustomClass p = (MyCustomClass)obj;
            return (txt == p.txt);
        }
    }
}
```

The above `Equals` method, not only it ensures that the object compared is `not null`, and also of the `same type` but it ensures that it compares all fields of them one by one.